# Get all custom sizes in srcset attribute

Tags: images

I have three custom sizes:

```
add_image_size( 'img-movil', 667, 667, true );
add_image_size( 'c200x200', 200, 200, true );
add_image_size( 'c400x400', 400, 400, true );
```

And I'm tring to get them into the srcset:

```
$img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $img_id, array( 'c200x200', 'c400x400', 'img-movil' ) );
srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>
```

But I get this into the srcset:

```
srcset="
    //localhost:3000/app/uploads/2016/12/6e55a1e9-4076-3649-9ebd-b5337b21120b-150x150.jpg 150w, 
    //localhost:3000/app/uploads/2016/12/6e55a1e9-4076-3649-9ebd-b5337b21120b-200x200.jpg 200w, 
    //localhost:3000/app/uploads/2016/12/6e55a1e9-4076-3649-9ebd-b5337b21120b-400x400.jpg 400w"
```

These are two custom sizes + one default size (150x150). `img-movil` size is not in the srcset. Why? How can I get the three custom sizes.

If I try to get only `img-movil` size:

```
$img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $img_id, 'img-movil' );
```

I get the default srceset (there are no custom sizes in srcset):

```
srcset=
    "//localhost:3000/app/uploads/2016/12/6e55a1e9-4076-3649-9ebd-b5337b21120b.jpg 631w, 
    //localhost:3000/app/uploads/2016/12/6e55a1e9-4076-3649-9ebd-b5337b21120b-300x240.jpg 300w"
```

So, It seems there is one image size that doesn't work at all (`img-movil`).

I tried to regenerate thumbnails, but this behavior persist.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pfff... I was four hours around this question and.. I got it. Is a very simple issue: original images are smaller than the custom size. So, custom sizes bigger than original images was not created for this images.

Comment: I've made that mistake, too! Glad you realized it :)